# Navbar transparent until scroll on Angular

Tags: html, css, angular, navbar

I am trying to make my navbar transparent. Upon scroll, I would like the navbar to have a solid background color. I have tried the various methods stated in other SO answers, but they mainly apply to javascript. I have tried using CSS properties such as `background-color` but to no avail. I believe that since scroll is used to trigger the color change, I might need to utilize `jQuery`?

header.html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md  sticky-top bg-light navbar-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand">App Name</a>
    <div class="container-fluid justify-content-end">
      <div class="navbar-header">
       <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
            <li><a class="nav-link" routerLink="/home" routerLinkActive="active">Home</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav-link" >About Us</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav-link" >Contact Us</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav-link" >Account</a></li>
          </ul>
       </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was planning to put it in a comment, but I can't since I don't have enough reputation so I'll just share it here.

Someone shared this on Twitter, however I forgot who did it. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sticky-disappearing-header

Based on your description, that link might provide the behaviour you actually intended to have. You definitely don't need `jQuery` just to get the scrolling event since you can use `fromEvent(window, "scroll")...`

You just need to adjust the `sticky.directive.ts` and the put the necessary styling in `styles.scss`.

**EDIT: adding code snippet from the StackBlitz**

```
    fromEvent(windowRef, "scroll")
      .pipe(
        map(() => windowRef.scrollY),
        pairwise(),
        map(([prev, next]) => next < THRESHOLD || prev > next),
        distinctUntilChanged(),
        startWith(true),
        takeUntil(destroy$)
      )
      .subscribe(stuck => {
        renderer.setAttribute(nativeElement, "data-stuck", String(stuck));
      });
```

Comment: it's better that you put in code the revelant part of the stackblitz, so the answer don't loose if the stackblitz change or deleted